# How to create vertical menu control in WPF

Tags: wpf

Iam trying to create vertical menu control but dont know from where to start. I am basically coming from winform to wpf and using telerik controls and this control which am using is called RadMenuControl.

Please view the video in link and suggest me accordingly with code and helping links from where i can start, thanks in advance.

[MenuItem Video](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=3C97297B44990FBF&resid=3C97297B44990FBF%21144&authkey=AMZfdRtvN--Q1iM)

Comment: Add some code you tried

Comment: Thanks, I am just asking where to start or which control to use available in WPF toolbox. I also uploaded video which i want to achieve exactly the same. So just need suggestions which control to use. any sample code will also be welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the ItemsPanel of Menu control.

Inheritance heirarchy : 
ItemsControl > MenuBase > Menu.

```
<Menu Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FontSize="18">
            <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <MenuItem Header="Styling">
                <MenuItem Header="Background"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Measurement">
                <MenuItem Header="Width"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Height"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Font"/>
        </Menu>
```

Comment: Thanks Anjum, Actually idea of your code is almost same, but i need collapsible control, just like treeview which can be simply collapse and un-collapse (exactly similar to menu in my video). Your provided menu control code is showing sub menus in the air and not collapsible. Please help.

Comment: you want your menu to get collapsed too ?

Comment: Thanks for the commitment, i shall wait :) And yes i need to collapsed  others if one is opened.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Telerik controls would you try RadPanelBar or RadOutlookBar. Surely your requirement will be satisfied one of these two controls.

[RadPanelBar](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/panelbar.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you need an similar functionality, you may consider using a `StackPanel` and keep stacking button items to them.

```
<StackPanel>
     <Button Content="Home"/>
     <Button Content="Edit"/>
     <Button Content="View"/>
</StackPanel>
```